# Specify a clientId during a REST api call in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, client-id

I am trying to make a REST api call from my node.js script to invoke a REST API in my Salesforce Org using OAuth.I wanted to track the Client from which the call was being made using the standard API usage report. However, as mentioned in the below link, inspite of setting the 
'Sforce-Call-Options' header to a random string, I am not able to see the Client Id being set.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_calloptions.htm

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Anee, do you have solved your problem ? On my side, I have currently the same problem.